# can i implement Openjdk and create a new JDK which is redistributable?, without passing tests of tck or any special license?

Tags: oracle, java-8, jvm, java

Can i implement OpenJdk and create my own JDK and redistribute it? without passing tests of Technology Compatibility Kit(TCK) or does it require any special license to be called it as JDK?

I just found that many of the third party vendors of JDK are written on top of OpenJdk by doing tweak changes, do they require any TCK (or) License for their Redistributable JDK ?

Comment: OpenJDK is licensed under GNU GPL, which means you can basically do whatever you want to it, as long as the result is licensed under GPL as well. So you could, for example remove any tests you don't like.
But why? Unless you want to do some super-high-level optimisation stuff, this sounds like an insane thing to do!?

Comment: OpenJDK is *already* a Java implementation.  You cannot implement it yourself.  You could, in principle, create your own, separate implementation, but this is fraught with danger -- consider that [Oracle has been suing Google](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2016/03/oracle-will-seek-a-staggering-9-3-billion-in-2nd-trial-against-google/) since 2010 for doing exactly that.

Comment: does it require any license or test to get passed as jdk ? to term it as my own specific jdk, which i can distribute with a vendor  or .. etc.   @Horst

Comment: I'd presume that 'JDK' is protected by oracle in some way, like @JohnBollinger is suggesting. So if you avoid it you maybe be alright (no solid legal advice though). But again, why would you do this??? It still sounds like you actually want to do something completely different!?

Comment: so, if you take an example of LINUX which is open source, and for suppose i have implemented in my own way(possibly a newer flavour), do i need to get copyright license from linux  to redistribute OR publish on net as a new LINUX Flavoour? similarly can i do it with OpenJDK which is open source? @JohnBollinger

Comment: @vinaybayyaram, the legal requirements on you, should you wish to undertake such an endeavor, depend on all sorts of details.  That you're now shifting to questions about a substantially different proposed line of development suggests that you are looking for generalities, but there are few such generalities to be had.  If you're serious, then you would be wise to consult an attorney.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IANAL. I have been working with OpenJDK for a while, but I don't understand all the legalities myself. Here's my understanding.

To be able to call something "Java" requires getting a license from the term "Java" which is owned by Oracle.

The TCK is not part of OpenJDK itself. It's a separate product available under a non-Free license. The process to get a TCK for OpenJDK is avialable here: http://openjdk.java.net/groups/conformance/JckAccess/ but I have heard stories where actually getting access is non-trivial. Your experience may vary.

You can definitely take OpenJDK modify it and release the results, claiming it is a fork of OpenJDK. This is pretty much what every Linux distribution does - they take OpenJDK and patch it (even if it's minor changes) and then build/release it. You can't call it "Java" unless you have Oracle's approval and you can't claim it has passed the TCK unless it actually has.

As far as I know, every single vendor that redistributes something and calls it Java has passed the TCK and has permission to call it "Java".

As for taking OpenJDK source, there's a long explanation here. I am 99.9% sure every single implementation uses the OpenJDK class libraries, at least. And every single OpenJDK contributor agrees to the Oracle Contributor Agreement which lets Oracle re-license OpenJDK under another license. So Oracle and other third party non-OpenJDK vendors can take OpenJDK, get a license from Oracle and publish their JDK under a license that's not the OpenJDK license.